# Подстановка нужной строки вместо нескольких условий с вызовом кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```js
var test = prompt("введите число от одного до трех");

if (test == 1)
 alert("один");
  
if (test == 2)
 alert("два");
  
if (test == 3)
 alert("три");
```

Существует ли возможность заменить его на подстановку нужного текста вместо вызова, а то есть как то так:

```
var test = prompt("введите число от одного до трех");

alert(if(test == 1){"один"};if(test == 2){"два"};if(test == 3){"три"};);
```

то есть нужна постановка текста вместо вызова функции с нужным параметром.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var test = prompt("введите число от одного до трех");

console.log({1:"один",2:"два",3:"три"}[test]);
// или так:
console.log(["один","два","три"][test-1]);
```

Comment: спасибо, исчерпывающий ответ

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, но по мне лучше создать переменную и switch/case...

```js
var test = prompt("введите число от одного до трех");

alert(test == 1?"один":test==2?"два":"три");
```

Answer (score 1):

Упростить можно. Вынесите получение слова по номеру в отдельную функцию. А вместо условий - используйте константу с хешем номеров и слов. Вот так:

```
function wordFromNumber(number) {
  const WORDS = { 1: "one",
                  2: "two",
                  3: "three"};

  return WORDS[number];
}

var number = prompt("Type a number from 1 to 3");
if (wordFromNumber(number) != undefined) {
  alert(wordFromNumber(number));
}
```

[Рабочий пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/d3gvL6b3/)

Также в коде я добавил условие. Если сопоставленного слова нет - не показывать `alert`.

Comment: а в чем тогда смысл отдельной функции? каждый раз при вызове один и тот же объект создавать?

Comment: реюзабельность.

Comment: да ладно, намного проще убрать функцию и сделать глобальный объект, он лучше чем глобальная функция :-)